# Can I copy thread.dumpstack() output to file

Tags: java

I am using jdk1.4 so I have to use thread.dumpstack() method to print call stack and I want all the dump into file,Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Wait...why are you using Java 1.4?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a Java solution, instead of Thread.dumpstack(), do

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("stacktrace.txt"));
Throwable t = new Throwable();
t.printStackTrace(out);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print the stack trace if you create a `Throwable` object:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( new FileWriter( "somefile.txt" ) );
new Throwable().printStackTrace( writer );
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple -- redirect stderr to a file on the command line that launches the program.

Comment: That will also put all kinds of other output into the file. Plus you cannot dynamically decide on the file name.

Comment: True, but the OP didn't specify any such concerns.